# AWS S3 bucket policy to block source IP address not working

Tags: amazon-s3

I know this question has been asked a few times and I have gone through a some documents and examples on this. But I am still not able to get it working.

I want to block access to my S3 bucket from one particular IP address and allow all others. I **do not** want to block instances belonging to an IAM role and hence I am using NotIpAddress Condition for this. Below is the policy I applied on my bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1486984747194",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllExceptOneIP",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "52.38.90.46"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But this policy isn't working. I am able to upload files to my bucket from this machine, I am using s3-curl.pl to temporarily upload my files.

Can someone please help me find what is wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't explicitly deny that IP. If you have a public ACL, all IP would be allowed by default. Create another statement with `Deny` effect for that IP.

Comment: @SergeyKovalev, thanks, can you help me with that. I tried 
`{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Id": "Policy1486984747194",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "AllowAll",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": "*"
   },
   "Action": "s3:*",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket"
  },
  {
   "Sid": "DenyOneIP",
   "Effect": "Deny",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": "*"
   },
   "Action": "s3:*",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket",
   "Condition": {
    "IpAddress": {
     "aws:SourceIp": "52.38.90.46"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}`
But this isn't working either.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong. Like @SergeyKovalev mentioned, we need to create another statement with deny effect. Since I was denying  Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket" and not arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*, I was able to upload files, only bucket listing was blocked from that IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block all actions to an S3 bucket from a particular IP, policy needs to have separate deny effect statement for that IP, sample:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1487062767078",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyIP",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "52.38.90.46"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Action and Resource can be changed based on what one needs to block.

Thanks a lot @SergeyKovalev for helping me with this solution.

Comment: change last condition with  NotIpAddress : "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "52.38.90.46"
                }
            }